# How to check if the Selection object contains two sibling 'Div' or 'P'

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, selection, siblings

I want to check a condition in which whether the user selection has any two or more div or paragraph sibling in it. 
am breaking my head on this am new to dom stuffs. Anybody came across such situation before or somebody can help me with the algorithm or logic to achieve this . any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: please share some relevant code like html, script and explain your problem

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you asked here, please share code snippet. Here i make for you example to achieve that. Since you did't post any code, then i'm not sure the example provided meet the expectations.

**HTML**

```
<div id="a">Click me
   <p></p>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>    
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#a').on('click', function(){
  var div = $(this).children('div').length;
  var p = $(this).children('p').length;

  if(div >= 2)
  {
    alert('div exists : ' + div);
    //do your stuff here
 }
 else
 {
    alert('i have div below than two');
    //do your stuff here if below than two
 }

//same goes with p
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/5gvLgrq7/1/)**

Comment: Will bind event to all the `div`s on page. Not a good practice.

Comment: Not sure this actually answers the question: *"whether the user **selection** has any two or more div or paragraph sibling in it"*. Meaning OP is probably looking for a solution involving [the Range interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)